# Async function in react doesn't react to state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want my `aysnc function` to react to state change so that it can terminate upon state change. What I have discovered is that it doesn't react to changing the state.

In the provided example I am changing the state from inside of the function, however I have tested it and changed the state **from outside of function** (Button click) and it **doesn't work either**.

```
const [testVariable, setTestVariable] = useState(false);

useEffect(()=> {
  testFunction();
}, [])

const testFunction = async () => {
  await timeout(1000);

  console.log("Setting test variable to: " + true);
  setTestVariable(true);

  await timeout(1000);
  
  console.log("Test variable is: " + testVariable);
}
```

Expected result is to see that the variable changed to true, however what I see is:
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

State variables never change their values. (Note that you can, have, and should declare them with `const` because they don't change).

Subsequent invokes of the component function will get a new state variable with the same name and a different value.

Your `testFunction` function has closed over the old state variable.

---

I suspect you could solve this with a reference:

```
const [testVariable, setTestVariable] = useState(false);
const reference = useRef();
reference.current = testVariable;
```

… and then have your function test the value of `reference.current` instead of `testVariable`.

---

This does, however, feel like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) where the real solution is "Use the return value from the function you pass to `useEffect` to stop whatever it is you want to stop" (and use `testVariable` as a dependency of `useEffect`).

Comment: @Quentin yes. Sorry but I have deleted my comment. For those who seek a TypeScript solution - you just need to use `useRef<VariableType>()`, where `VariableType` is whatever your `useState` holds. For example `boolean`

Comment: This is not the proper use case for `useRef` - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref.
`useRef` should be used to pass stateful variables from a child component to a parent component. (example: a detailed view of an element has a ref to the value of the same element in a parent list, to update the parent based on the changed properties).

Comment: @KimBrunJørgensen — Please read the link  you just shared more carefully. It says "A common use case is to access a child imperatively". Common does not mean "only acceptable". It also says "However, useRef() is useful for more than the ref attribute. It’s handy for keeping any mutable value around". Also note the final paragraph of my answer where I suggested that a better solution probably existed but the question didn't provide enough information about the real problem.

Answer (score 3):

state update in react is async means that your state will be changed in next render cycle.
you can useEffect hook to track if any state is changed or not.

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(testVariable);
}, [testVariable]);
```

Comment: Yes I am aware of that but I need to terminate a `for` inside an async function on state change

Comment: In that case, you should store the new value of `testVariable` in a const inside the `async function` and use that as the reference for the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
const [testVariable, setTestVariable] = useState(false);

useEffect(()=> {
  testFunction();
}, [])

const testFunction = async () => {
  await timeout(1000);

  console.log("Setting test variable to: " + true);

  let newTestVariable = true;  
  setTestVariable(newTestVariable);

  await timeout(1000);
  
  console.log("Test variable is: " + newTestVariable);
}
```

Changing the state variable is an asynchronous operation and works with something called the event loop. It will not immediately get updated when you did setTestVariable(true).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue solved it by adding anonymous function inside setState.

```
setState((state) => state="value")
```

if you are toggling Boolean

```
setState((state) => !state)
```

Answer (score -2):

The `async function` *is* changing the state, but you're logging `testVariable` in the same lifecycle, which is why it looks as though the state wasn't changed.

If you instead change the code to be

```js
const [testVariable, setTestVariable] = React.useState(false)

console.log('testVariable', testVariable)
React.useEffect(() => {
  testFunction()
}, [])

const testFunction = async () => {
  await timeout(1000)
  setTestVariable(!testVariable)
}

return <h2>{testVariable}</h2>
```

It will log the output:

```
testVariable false
testVariable false
testVariable true
testVariable true
```

The reason it's showing two logs for both `false` and `true` is because the `console.log` is outside the `React.useEffect(() => {}, [])` (which is equivalent to componentDidMount for stateful React components). React is first executing the `console.log` before the component mounts, then after the component mounts it executes the code inside `React.useEffect` and rerenders the component, thus executing the `console.log` statement again.

To only log once you would have to change the `React.useEffect` to:

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
  console.log('testVariable', testVariable)
  testFunction()
}, [testVariable])
```

Adding a properties to the array arguments `[testVariable]`, changes the `React.useEffect` from being a `componentDidMount` equivalent function to be a function chat executes on `componentDidMount` and for every new state of `testVariable`.